# php can't start because fbclient.dll is missing

Tags: php, iis, webserver

I'm getting an error when I try to run any .PHP script.

I has this error:

> `php can't start because fbclient.dll is missing`

I'm currently running Win7 64bit, IIS 7.5
I don't have fbclient.dll in my PHP.ini file.
I don't have firebird installed.

How can I fix this error and get PHP script running?

Comment: You must have it in your ini file, are you sure you're looking at the right one?

Comment: I did a complete search of the entire C: drive for any PHP.ini and I only have one.

Comment: I did have php_interbase enabled.  I have disabled it.  I am now getting this error: http://i67.tinypic.com/s12jp5.jpg

Comment: Yes, that's an entirely different question. Unfortunately you won't be able to google *screenshots* of error messages.

Comment: The same information that is in the link is: I am now getting the error HTTP Error 500.0 Not Found The resource you are looking for has been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unabailable. Handler php-7.0.1 Error Code 0x80070585 Requested URL theoffice.la:443/phpinfo.php C:\MyDocuments2\Web\phpinfo.php The file is in that folder.

Answer (score 0):

If you have the `php_pdo_firebird` and/or `php_interbase` extensions enabled, PHP will require that `fbclient.dll` be available.

Since you are not using Firebird, you need to make sure that both of those extensions are disabled.

Answer (score 0):

If you have the php_pdo_firebird and/or php_interbase extensions enabled, PHP will require that fbclient.dll be available.

Since you are not using Firebird, you need to make sure that both of those extensions are disabled.

So , to disable 
- open php.ini
- append ; to extension=php_pdo_firebird.dll and extension=php_interbase.dll
Ex : ;extension=php_pdo_firebird.dll
     ;extension=php_interbase.dll